# C# What makes a difference when I used Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I made a following C# codes using Regex Class. But it doesn't work that I think.

```
string s = Regex.Match("binary", "b(?=inary)").Value;
string _s = Regex.Replace("binary", "b(?=inary)", ", ");

Console.WriteLine("result is {0}{1}", s, _s);
```

Following codes are just different used Methods.

But the output is different each other like
    "result is b, inary".

```
string s = Regex.Match("binary", "b(?=inary)").Value;

string _s = Regex.Replace("binary", "b(?=inary)", ", ");
```

What makes a difference?

Please Give Me Some Advice!!!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with that regex? What is expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

The `Match` function is intended to return information about what text matches the specified expression. Since `b` matches the pattern in this context, it will only output `b`. `Replace` performs some change on the matched text and returns the resulting changed text. This is why you see `, inary` returned - it replaced the `b` with `,` causing the whole result to return `, inary`.

### Match

[`b`]`inary` => `b`

### Replace

[`b`]`inary` => [`,`]`inary`